# Validation against Database type ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a few fields in a webforms and currently I'm not implementing any form of validation but I intend to do so.

Suppose I have the following `UpdateParameters` in my `SQLDataSource`:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="active" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

And a textbox for each of the fields. I tried, but couldn't find a built-in way to validate the `TextBoxes` against the parameter type, so for example, the `Date_TextBox` would validate that the input is in a `DateTime` format. I know I can do custom validators with regexes and whatnot, but I feel there's a built-in, simple way of doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `CompareValidator`??

You can specify the type like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="The type is not a valid integer" 
    ControlToValidate="txt"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Integer"
    />
<asp:Button Text="Test valdiation" runat="server" />
```

The available types are:

- String.   Specifies a string data type.
- Integer.  Specifies a 32-bit signed integer data type.
- Double.   Specifies a double-precision floating-point number data type.
- Date. Specifies a date data type.
- Currency. Specifies a monetary data type.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! ASP.NET documentation is so abundant that such "simple" questions are usually buried under tons of documentation on complex topics.